# Angular async query request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http

I have 2 examples of using `query` in AngularJS:

First :

```
requests.query().$promise.then(function(requestResponse) {
    myFunction(requestResponse);
});
```

Second :

```
requests.query(function(requestResponse) {
    myFunction(requestResponse);
});
```

Are this 2 samples same? In both cases is it used promises to get data async?

Comment: According to the documentation - They are the same, but to `$promise` gives you raw access to the `$http` promise. Maybe you'd use it when you need access to the `notify` callback of the promise that doesn't exist in the resource (You only have access to the `success` and the `error` callback when using resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both are the same thing except you can pass `null` (no parameters) in the 2nd example to avoid confusion:

```
requests.query(null, function(requestResponse) {
         myFunction(requestResponse);
});
```

Looking at your question, it looks like the `requests` is created by [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) service which provides 5 methods and the `query` method is one of those 5 methods.

All those 5 methods return an object which has a `$promise` object where you can use the `then()` function for success & failure cases. So your first snippet is based on this.

Now, all those 5 methods also accept last two parameters as success & failure callbacks which are the shorthand for the `then()` function so here comes your second snippet (Angular internally uses that `$promise` returned by the `$http` call).

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be
>   invoked with the following parameters:
>
> - HTTP GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], [success],
>     [error])`
> - non-GET "class" actions: `Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])`
> - non-GET instance actions: `instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])`

So here comes your second snippet. So the summary is, yes both are one and the same thing.